# Alternatives for accessing PHP functions

Tags: php

Currently, I'm developing an application using standard PHP. As such, there are assorted functions that are called from forms.  Some examples include registration, login, logout, and others.

Rather than creating a separate file for each function, I'm using a `phpscripts.php` file in the includes folder.  To execute a function from html input, I pad the URL with `?action=functionName`.  Inside the script file, I use a switch/case tree to execute the proper function based on the `S_GET['action']` variable.

Is there a better way to implement HTML calls to PHP functions?

Comment: could i just hit your url with ?action=deleteALL or some other guess

Comment: Consider learning to use a [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/).

Comment: @Dagon, no.  That wouldn't work, as all other functionality is dependent on POST values.  GET is only used to direct button actions to functions.

Comment: @meager, that would be idea, but one requirement for this project is to maximize drop-in functionlity and minimize external dependencies.  This means no frameworks...

Comment: both can be posted you to the url get\post I would never expose a function name like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is the correct way to interface a HTML form with a PHP script. Other alternatives would include employing URL rewriting (to convert something like `/actions/functionname/param` to `?action=functionname&param=x`), but the basic principle remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

For your sanity... consider having one script that handles all requests like your above. Something like /process_action.php. You do handle unified actions such as: checking to make sure the function exists, checking for a logged in user, connecting to a database, creating shared resources, etc...

If you're using Apache, you can make the URLs pretty by using mod rewrite. You can turn

```
/actions/function/?restofquery
```

into

```
/process_action.php?action=function&restofquery
```

by using something like the following placed in a .htaccess file in your website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/actions/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /process_action.php?action=$1&%1 [L]
```

As a side note, your question sounds like you're on the verge of discovering the [model/view/controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). There are several great frame-works, but don't let that discourage you from rolling your own. Learn by doing :)

Comment: I'm experienced with Java MVC and framweworks, particularly Grails.  Problem is, this project has a minimal-dependency requirement, or I'd start by integrating Zend or CodeIgniter in a heartbeat.